# How do you use entity framework migrations for new and existing databases?

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have an existing database and I use EF migrations to get its initial state.

```
Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations
add-migration Initial
```

If I go ahead and run update-database, I get an error that my objects already exist.  The solution I'm told is to remove the code in the Up() and Down() methods.  That works fine.  Now I can modify my models and add new migrations and then update to them accordingly.

But what do I do when I want to create a new database?  I went ahead and restored the code in the Up/Down methods, and that worked for creating a new DB, but if I tried applying it to an existing database I'm back to the objects already exist.  I'm guessing I need to be able to initialize the history table on the existing database.

Comment: I learned using this video. hope it helps http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbDOhCjjxSY

Comment: no, that video is only for NEW databases.

Comment: so check part 2 it tolds you how, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I found a sortof workaround which will probably do the trick.

Make sure you delete the _MigrationHistory table on the existing database.  Run the following in the PMC

```
Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force
add-migration Initial
Update-Database -Script
```

The last command will generate a new SQL script and open in your IDE.  Remove the code in the Initial Up() Down() methods.  You can create a new database, then execute this script on that database and continue to use migrations.

Hopefully I can find a more elegant way of doing this.